# C2Call Push Notification

Tags: ios, ios7, apple-push-notifications

Could you help me check if I miss anything during the configuration, because I couldn't receive notification once the app was killed. If the app was just minimising, a notification will be shown for call, but for instant messaging, the phone only vibrate with a pop sound but showed no notification.
Using C2Call How to call below method in AppDelegate sub-class.

```
[super application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken]; 



- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {
    //[self registerDeviceToken:devToken];
    // Get Bundle Info for Remote Registration (handy if you have more than one app)
    NSString *appName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
    NSString *appVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

    // Check what Notifications the user has turned on.  We registered for all three, but they may have manually disabled some or all of them.
    //

    NSUInteger rntypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];


    // Set the defaults to disabled unless we find otherwise...

    NSString *pushBadge = @"disabled";
    NSString *pushAlert = @"disabled";
    NSString *pushSound = @"disabled";

    if(rntypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge){
        pushBadge = @"enabled";
    }
    else if(rntypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert){
        pushAlert = @"enabled";
    }
    else if(rntypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound){
        pushSound = @"enabled";
    }
    else if(rntypes == ( UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)){         pushBadge = @"enabled";
        pushAlert = @"enabled";
    }
    else if(rntypes == ( UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)){         pushBadge = @"enabled";
        pushSound = @"enabled";
    }
    else if(rntypes == ( UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)){         pushAlert = @"enabled";
        pushSound = @"enabled";
    }
    else if(rntypes == ( UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)){
        pushBadge = @"enabled";
        pushAlert = @"enabled";
        pushSound = @"enabled";
    }

    // Get the users Device Model, Display Name, Unique ID, Token & Version Number
    UIDevice *dev = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    // NSString *deviceUuid=dev.uniqueIdentifier;
    NSString *deviceUuid = [[dev identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    NSString *deviceName = dev.name;
    NSString *deviceModel = dev.model;
    NSString *deviceSystemVersion = dev.systemVersion;

    //Prepare the Device Token for Registration (remove spaces and < >)
    NSString *deviceToken = [[[[devToken description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""]                               stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
    NSString *urlString = [@"/pushservice/apns/user/register"stringByAppendingString:@"r=user/register"];
     NSLog(@"devicetoken length: %i", [deviceToken length]);
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&appname="];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:appName];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&appversion="];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:appVersion];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&deviceuid="];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:deviceUuid];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&devicetoken="];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:deviceToken];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&devicename="];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:deviceName];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&devicemodel="];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:deviceModel];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&deviceversion="];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:deviceSystemVersion];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&pushbadge="];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:pushBadge];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&pushalert="];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:pushAlert];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&pushsound="];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:pushSound];

    NSUserDefaults *def=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [def setObject:deviceToken forKey:@"token"];
    [def synchronize];
   //[super application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {

    [super application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken];

   //[self registerDeviceToken:devToken];

  // Get Bundle Info for Remote Registration (handy if you have more than one app)

  NSString *appName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];

  NSString *appVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

  // Check what Notifications the user has turned on.  We registered for all three, but they may have manually disabled some or all of them.
//

  NSUInteger rntypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];


  // Set the defaults to disabled unless we find otherwise...

  NSString *pushBadge = @"disabled";
NSString *pushAlert = @"disabled";
NSString *pushSound = @"disabled";

if(rntypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge){
    pushBadge = @"enabled";
}
else if(rntypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert){
    pushAlert = @"enabled";
}
else if(rntypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound){
    pushSound = @"enabled";
}
else if(rntypes == ( UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)){         pushBadge = @"enabled";
    pushAlert = @"enabled";
}
else if(rntypes == ( UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)){         pushBadge = @"enabled";
    pushSound = @"enabled";
}
else if(rntypes == ( UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)){         pushAlert = @"enabled";
    pushSound = @"enabled";
}
else if(rntypes == ( UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)){
    pushBadge = @"enabled";
    pushAlert = @"enabled";
    pushSound = @"enabled";
}

// Get the users Device Model, Display Name, Unique ID, Token & Version Number
UIDevice *dev = [UIDevice currentDevice];
// NSString *deviceUuid=dev.uniqueIdentifier;

NSString *deviceUuid = [[dev identifierForVendor] UUIDString];

NSString *deviceName = dev.name;

NSString *deviceModel = dev.model;

NSString *deviceSystemVersion = dev.systemVersion;

//Prepare the Device Token for Registration (remove spaces and < >)

NSString *deviceToken = [[[[devToken description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""]                               stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];

NSString *urlString = [@"/pushservice/apns/user/register"stringByAppendingString:@"r=user/register"];

 NSLog(@"devicetoken length: %i", [deviceToken length]);

urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&appname="];

urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:appName];

urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&appversion="];

urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:appVersion];

urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&deviceuid="];

urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:deviceUuid];

urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&devicetoken="];

urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:deviceToken];

urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&devicename="];

urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:deviceName];

urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&devicemodel="];

urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:deviceModel];

urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&deviceversion="];

urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:deviceSystemVersion];

urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&pushbadge="];

urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:pushBadge];

urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&pushalert="];

urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:pushAlert];

urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&pushsound="];

urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:pushSound];

NSUserDefaults *def=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[def setObject:deviceToken forKey:@"token"];

[def synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Error:-- undeclare Identifier didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code:--

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {
  //[self registerDeviceToken:devToken];
  // Get Bundle Info for Remote Registration (handy if you have more than one app)
  NSString *appName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
  NSString *appVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

  // Check what Notifications the user has turned on.  We registered for all three, but they may have manually disabled some or all of them.
  //

  NSUInteger rntypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];

  // Set the defaults to disabled unless we find otherwise...

  NSString *pushBadge = @"disabled";
  NSString *pushAlert = @"disabled";
  NSString *pushSound = @"disabled";

  if(rntypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge){
      pushBadge = @"enabled";
  }
  else if(rntypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert){
      pushAlert = @"enabled";
  }
  else if(rntypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound){
      pushSound = @"enabled";
  }
  else if(rntypes == ( UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)){         pushBadge = @"enabled";
      pushAlert = @"enabled";
  }
  else if(rntypes == ( UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)){         pushBadge = @"enabled";
      pushSound = @"enabled";
  }
  else if(rntypes == ( UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)){         pushAlert = @"enabled";
      pushSound = @"enabled";
  }
  else if(rntypes == ( UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)){
      pushBadge = @"enabled";
      pushAlert = @"enabled";
      pushSound = @"enabled";
  }

  // Get the users Device Model, Display Name, Unique ID, Token & Version Number
  UIDevice *dev = [UIDevice currentDevice];
  // NSString *deviceUuid=dev.uniqueIdentifier;
  NSString *deviceUuid = [[dev identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
  NSString *deviceName = dev.name;
  NSString *deviceModel = dev.model;
  NSString *deviceSystemVersion = dev.systemVersion;

  //Prepare the Device Token for Registration (remove spaces and < >)
  NSString *deviceToken = [[[[devToken description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""]                               stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
  NSString *urlString = [@"/pushservice/apns/user/register"stringByAppendingString:@"r=user/register"];
  NSLog(@"devicetoken length: %i", [deviceToken length]);
  urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&appname="];
  urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:appName];
  urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&appversion="];
  urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:appVersion];
  urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&deviceuid="];
  urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:deviceUuid];
  urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&devicetoken="];
  urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:deviceToken];
  urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&devicename="];
  urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:deviceName];
  urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&devicemodel="];
  urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:deviceModel];
  urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&deviceversion="];
  urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:deviceSystemVersion];
  urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&pushbadge="];
  urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:pushBadge];
  urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&pushalert="];
  urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:pushAlert];
  urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&pushsound="];
  urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:pushSound];
  strGlobalDeviceToken=deviceToken;
  NSLog(@"deviceToken %@",strGlobalDeviceToken);
  NSUserDefaults *def=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [def setObject:deviceToken forKey:@"token"];
  [def synchronize];

  [super application: application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:devToken];

}